# help understanding sudo -s

Tags: bash, sudo

I was trying out a command yesterday that put my computer into hibernation mode. The first line in the command sequence was `sudo -s` which made my command line go from

```
userName@computerName:~$
```

to

```
root@computerName:~#
```

I looked at the manual page for sudo and it did not give any explanation as to why this happen or what mode it had entered.

What does the `root` and `#` mean in the second command line tag? what does this mode allow you to do and how do I get out of it? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does the root and # mean in the second command line tag?

It means you edit the system as "root". That is 1 more level up than from "sudo" and 1 more up from your normal users activities  ...

> what does this mode allow you to do

... and (almost) all permissions checks are neglected. So if want you can seriously destroy your system with a single command.

> and how do I get out of it?

Type

```
 exit
```